# UINavigationBar custom background hides title on newly pushed viewcontroller

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, customization, title

I have a navigation controller with a custom navBar with an image background that I setup like  this:

```
homeViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];
mainController     = [[MainController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeViewController];

// ### CUSTOM GRADIANT BLUE TOOLBAR
UIImageView *customTabView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1024.0, 44.0)];
[customTabView setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"navbar" ofType:@"png"]]];
customTabView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[mainController.navigationBar insertSubview:customTabView atIndex:0];

[customTabView release];
```

In the homeViewController viewDidLoad I set the title like this:

```
self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"app.title", nil);
```

and it displays perfectly fine. BUT when I push a new controller and set the title inside it the same way, it doesn't show up anymore:

```
Glossary *glossaryController = [[Glossary alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController: glossaryController animated:YES];
```

I do not understand the cause of this problem since the title display fine for the root view controller using exactly the same technique and I cannot find anyone with the same issue.
Inside glossary viewDidLoad:

```
self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"app.glossary", nil);
```

I think the title is actually "there" but hidden under the custom view but I don't see how that is possible since I inserted that custom view at the bottom (index:0). Unless pushing a new view controller affects this? In which case I would appreciate any input explaining what exactly happens and how I can deal with it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I'm experiencing something similar

Comment: I was assigned to another project so never did get to find out, sorry. If you ever find out yourself please add your solution here, could help future readers and I would upvote your answer. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this before and I found the easiest answer is to use a custom image for the title.  That may not be practical for you because you may not know the title or you may have so many possible titles that making an image for each is not practical.